# Creating a folder S3 AWS SDK-V2 with Golang

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, amazon-s3, directory

How to create a folder AWS SDK-V2 S3 bucket using golang?
I have not found any documentation on the create of a folder.

Answer (score 6):

There are no "folders" or "directories" on AWS S3.

This is only a representative thing in the console GUI and many other tools. The file you store has the full path as it's key.

Comment: Therefore, @RandolphHill, instead of "folder" think "prefix".